# Predefined key value spacing in Material UI

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to add predefined spacing key/values in Material UI theme so that I can use the key name in order to define the spacing value?

```
spacing: {
        no: 0,
        xs: 2,
        sm: 4,
        md: 8,
        lg: 16
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a custom object with the required properties in the mui `theme`, and then you can use that in the stylings.
example:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  custom: {
    spacing: {
      no: 0,
      xs: 2,
      sm: 4,
      md: 8,
      lg: 16
    }
  }
});
```

Now you can use these properties in several ways like in `makeStyles` or using `useTheme` hook.

`makeStyles` example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    demo:{
        margin: theme.custom.spacing.sm
    }
}));
```

`useTheme` example:

```
export default function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Grid spacing={theme.custom.spacing.sm}>
      
    </Grid>
  );
}
```